# IBM MobileFirst- JSDT UI Error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio, eclipse-jsdt

I am trying to install IBM Mobile First foundation plugin in eclipse. But I'm receiving the following error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: IBM MobileFirst Studio Plugins 8.0.0.v20180528_0848 (com.ibm.mfp.feature.feature.group 8.0.0.v20180528_0848)
  Missing requirement: Web Tools Plugin 7.2.0.v20180528_0848 (com.ibm.etools.webtools 7.2.0.v20180528_0848) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui [1.1.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: IBM MobileFirst Studio Plugins 8.0.0.v20180528_0848 (com.ibm.mfp.feature.feature.group 8.0.0.v20180528_0848)
    To: com.ibm.etools.webtools [7.2.0.v20180528_0848]
```

From where do I get this dependency? If it is a jar file, where shall I place it so that eclipse could pick it up while installing mobile first plugin.

The Eclipse IDE is Neon (and Mobile first only supports Neon version).

I am new to eclipse, and am sorry if this is a rudimentary question.

Regards

Aditya

Comment: In _Window > Preferences: Install/Update > Available Software Sites_ do you have the Neon update site with the location `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/`? If no, add it. If yes, make sure in _Help > Install New Software..._ the option _Contact all update sites during install to find required software_ is enabled.

Comment: Hi @howlger I checked both the places that you have mentioned. The site is enabled in the preferences and contact all sites is also enabled. Is it related to eclipse version? Will this work on mars?

Comment: What error message do you get if you add the update site `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars/`?

Comment: @howlger your suggestion proved to be the best. Please have a look at answer section :)

Answer (score 0):

For people facing this problem, here is the solution:

Go to windows -> preferences -> install/update -> available software sites -> add `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars` and ensure it is ✅ (checked).

Now come back to marketplace to install mobile first plugin. It should work.

Thank you @howlger :)